# How to use PuTTY to login MySQL account directly?

Tags: login, mysql, putty, auto-login, remote-login

How to PuTTY access MySQL directly with MySQL ac but skip the Ubuntu login? I would like to skip the Ubuntu login to access the MySQL server with MySQL account directly by PuTTY.

Thanks!

Comment: You use PuTTY on a local machine to connect to a remote SSH server, where you need to start a `mysql` client. Instead, you could run a local `mysql` client and connect to the MySQL server, bypassing SSH completely. But PuTTY will not do that.

Comment: If you see any issues with my answer please leave a comment below answer. I did not test this but used a template we have for things like this.

Comment: It would really help if you describe what you want to do in a little more detail. What is the difference between the Ubuntu account the MySQL account? What do you mean by "access MySQL" -- this usually means to access and use the database from a program, such as, for example, Excel or PHP.

Comment: Hi All,
i would like to though PuTTY to do the effect like inputting the below command in Window cmd :
mysql -h <mysql_server_url> -P <port_number> -u <username> -p<password>

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a specific account for this. For instance a user putty: `adduser putty`.
- Create a configuration file in the home directory of your user using [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html).
- Edit `.bash_profile` for that account and add:

  ```
  mysql --login-path=/home/putty/.mylogin.cnf {database}
  ```

  And any other parameters you need but it will take user and password from the configuration file. You could also add the database to the configuration.
- Set Putty up to login with that account and password. You can do this directly or using ssh auth keys (but that last one also requires you to set this up in Ubuntu).

But why go through so many hoops and not install [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html)?

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use a graphic MySQL client instead, my personal favourite being DBeaver.

Comment: Thanks Rinzind. I think via PuTTY port 3306 to login to MySQL is more secure. Also, for the security reason, it is not allowed to set the account and password in PuTTY. Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: "port 3306 to login to MySQL is more secure." No it is not. Automating it is never secure and is always to be considered insecure. "it is not allowed to set the account and password in PuTTY." If that is not allowed: putting user and password into putty is as unsafe as any other method so this will be impossible. Manually typing username and password is the secure method. You can use ssh public/private keys to log into Ubuntu but that is not secure; that only prevents access other than those that hold the ssh key and is the same a using a user/pwd in putty itself.

Comment: Pleas add additional information into the question and do not use comments for that @DeniseWun I will remove this once that is done.

Answer (score 0):

Putty doesn't have `mysql client` in it. So you `can't` connect directly.
You need some kind of mysql client to connect to the mysql server.